# Issues with comma delimiter and number of columns when reading in csv file in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, filehelpers

I'm a fairly new coder, and everything I'm working on I have completely taught myself. I'm trying to read in CSV files and then eventually output them to an SQL server. I read a lot about how to do this and decided to implement it using the FileHelpers in Visual Studio 2015.

An issue that I'm running into is that some of the data itself contain commas (ex: 9,500). I know many people suggest putting quotes around the number. However, I am not the one inputting the numbers. The file is just sent to me that way, and I am supposed to write the code to input it into an SQL server. **Is there any other way to fix that issue other than quotation marks?** Also, some of my rows are shorter than others.

```
ex: Joe, John, Jim, Ben
    35,  42,   35,  60
    A,   B,     C,  D
    40,  50
```

So for example, that last row does not have the same amount of values. They are not null either. I have already addressed null values.

It just doesn't include them, and when I go running my code, I get an error-

> " Line: 29 Column: 4. Delimiter ',' not found

after field 'Hours' (the record has fewer fields, the delimiter is wrong, or the next field must be marked as optional)."

How would I go about fixing these issues? When I remove the rows containing comma values such as 9,500 and when I also remove the incomplete rows, my code works perfectly. However, I need it to work for all of the data. Thanks

Comment: you can't fix!! You need to ask your file provider for giving a standard CSV file; Column should n't vary; if there is no value, there should be a `,` still... Column values should be enclosed in `quote`, if one of the values are expected to contain `,`.  Or switch to another separator like `;`

Comment: How can you tell if `9,500` is one value or two?

Comment: " The file is just sent to me that way" Here is the problem, you can't property separate fields by `,` when the values contain unescaped `,`.

Comment: Try to post some sample inputs, and we can see what can be salvaged from that.

Comment: Two questions: based on the example row above: Is "60 A" a real item, or should it be "60, A"?  Also, you wrote your CSV as having spaces after each comma.  Could your delimiter actually *be* `<comma><space>` rather than just `<comma>`? If so, your delimiter problem is solved.

Comment: For incomplete rows: is there a rule or heuristic you can apply to know which columns are missing?  If so, you may be able to preprocess the rows before parsing with FileHelpers.

Comment: Is it possible that the columns are fixed width, and not CSV (from you example this looks like a possibility)? If so the processing would be completely different. A larger data sample would help.

Comment: I used the spaces just to make it easier to read and show that there are some rows that are shorter than others. It is written as a csv. Also, i know the value is 9,500 because they told me that is what the number is supposed to be. It's an office report that is being sent to me so I guess sometimes some of the columns don't apply depending on the day. That is where I am having the issue

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
[FieldOptional]
```

over the 3th and 4th column, like:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MyRecord
{

   public string Field1;
   public string Field2;
   [FieldOptional]
   public string Field3;
   [FieldOptional]
   public string Field4;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to fix that issue other than quotation marks?

Yes, you could perform a string replace on a comma-space combination with something else like an asterisk.  And then split on the asterisk or special character to get an array of items.

```
string input = "Joe, John, Jim, Ben 35, 42, 35, 60, 9,500";
string output = input.Replace(", ", "*");
string[] myArray = output.Split('*');
```

In a case where you had the value 9,500, it would interpret that value as one item rather than two, because there is no space after the comma.

But, you're better off having those values arrive in quotes in your CSV.  If you've got Excel installed, add row of numbers, with some containing commas. Then save your workbook as a CSV, and then open the CSV in Notepad. You'll see that numbers with commas are wrapped in double quotes.  Here is an example from a test I just performed.

```
Numbers entered in a row:  9,000, 1, 8, 7, 500, 125,050
CSV text: "9,000",1,8,7,500,"125,050"
```

I hope that helps you out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The "short row" issue can be fixed in software fairly easily:

- Load each row whole, into a List(of String)
- Calculate the number of cells for each row
- Get the maximum number of cells used
- For each "short row", add blank cells until it matches the maximum

However if people are entering commas in numbers (e.g. 9,500) then you are stuffed, and will need to ask for a properly-formatted CSV file.

From the example data in the question, its a "short row" issue.